# Linux bash script to change ownership for directories, sub-directories and files

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script for changing files and directories ownerships.

I need to change the owners of the files and directories inside nfs area. In this area, files and directories ownerships belongs to some user ids. (somehow nfs area change all the directory and file owners to corresponding user id numbers. For instance file1 ownership belongs to 2100 and 2100 is an id that belongs to user db1). Without realizing it, we upgrade our server and change the user id's. So now, inside nfs area I need to change all directory and files ownerships to the new corresponding users.

The script gets directory/file owners (names) to an array and directory/file paths to another array. **When I print arrays, I can see that the file owner names corresponds to the file paths.**.  Than inside a for loop, if directory and file owner name is equal to a static name (for instance 2100) , I will change the file ownership for the new corresponding user. The problem is when I run the script, it cant change ownership of all of directories and files. It only change some of them.

The output before running the script:

```
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]# ll
total 15
drwxr-xr-x 3 2100 3000    7 Nov 23 13:49 directory1
drwxr-xr-x 3 2400 3000    6 Nov 23 13:52 directory2
drwxr-xr-x 3 2300 3000    7 Nov 23 13:53 directory3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1016 Nov 23 14:01 modify.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1516 Nov 19 10:13 modifyzfs.sh
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]# cd directory1/
[root@eeprepo01 directory1]# ll
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 2100 5000 4 Nov 23 13:49 directory1_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2100 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 2500 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2300 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 2400 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file4
[root@eeprepo01 directory1]# cd directory1_2/
[root@eeprepo01 directory1_2]# ll
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 2100 5000 0 Nov 23 13:49 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 2100 5000 0 Nov 23 13:49 file2
[root@eeprepo01 directory1_2]#
```

As you can see, files and directories belongs to some numbers which are some id's that corresponds to actual users. The output after running the script is below:

```
    [root@eeprepo01 testscript]# bash -x modify.sh 
    + path='/nfspath/testscripts/testscript/*'
    + path_owners=($(find $path -printf '%u\n'))
    ++ find /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modify.sh /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modifyzfs.sh -printf '%u\n'
    + echo 2100 2400 root 2100 2100 2300 2500 2100 2400 2500 2300 2400 2500 2300 2600 2500 2300 2500 2600 2610 2710 2610 2710 2100 2710 2400 2300 root root
    2100 2400 root 2100 2100 2300 2500 2100 2400 2500 2300 2400 2500 2300 2600 2500 2300 2500 2600 2610 2710 2610 2710 2100 2710 2400 2300 root root
    + path_owners_names=($(find $path -print))
    ++ find /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modify.sh /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modifyzfs.sh -print
    + echo /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file4 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file4 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modify.sh /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modifyzfs.sh
    /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file4 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory2/directory2_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file3 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file4 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/directory3_1/directory3_2/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file2 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory3/file1 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modify.sh /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/modifyzfs.sh
    + j=0
    + for i in '$path'
    + [[ 2100 -eq 2100 ]]
    ++ chown db1:5000 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1
    + j=1
    + for i in '$path'
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2100 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2600 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2500 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2300 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2610 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2710 ]]
    + [[ 2400 -eq 2400 ]]
    ++ chown db7:5000 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/file4
    + j=2
    + for i in '$path'
    + [[ root -eq 2100 ]]
    + [[ root -eq 2600 ]]
    + [[ root -eq 2500 ]]
    + [[ root -eq 2300 ]]
    + [[ root -eq 2610 ]]

+ [[ root -eq 2710 ]]
+ [[ root -eq 2400 ]]
+ j=3
+ for i in '$path'
+ [[ 2100 -eq 2100 ]]
++ chown db1:5000 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file1
+ j=4
+ for i in '$path'
+ [[ 2100 -eq 2100 ]]
++ chown db1:5000 /nfspath/testscripts/testscript/directory1/directory1_2/file2
+ j=5
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]#
```

I echoed the arrays to show that arrays take all the values. I also run the script with bash -x and I see that the for loop only run for 6 items.

After running script, the output is like this:

```
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]# ll
total 15
drwxr-xr-x 3 db1  5000    7 Nov 23 13:49 directory1
drwxr-xr-x 3 2400 3000    6 Nov 23 13:52 directory2
drwxr-xr-x 3 2300 3000    7 Nov 23 13:53 directory3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1016 Nov 23 14:01 modify.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1516 Nov 19 10:13 modifyzfs.sh
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]# cd directory1/
[root@eeprepo01 directory1]# ll
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 db1  5000 4 Nov 23 13:49 directory1_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2100 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 2500 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2300 3000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 db7  5000 0 Nov 23 13:48 file4
[root@eeprepo01 directory1]# cd directory1_2/
[root@eeprepo01 directory1_2]# ll
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 db1 5000 0 Nov 23 13:49 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 db1 5000 0 Nov 23 13:49 file2
[root@eeprepo01 directory1_2]# cd ../../
[root@eeprepo01 testscript]# cd directory2/
[root@eeprepo01 directory2]# ll
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 2500 3000 5 Nov 23 13:52 directory2_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2500 3000 0 Nov 23 13:50 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 2300 3000 0 Nov 23 13:50 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 2400 3000 0 Nov 23 13:50 file3
```

The script only change the directory1, directory1_2 and file 1 and 2's ownership.

The script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/nfspath/testscripts/*"

path_owners=($(find $path -printf '%u\n'))
echo ${path_owners[@]}
path_owners_names=($(find $path -print))
echo ${path_owners_names[@]}
j=0

for i in $path
do
    
        
    if [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2100 ]]; then
        `chown db1:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
        
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2600 ]]; then
        `chown db2:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
        
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2500 ]]; then
        `chown db3:5000${path_owners_names[$j]}`
        
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2300 ]]; then
        `chown db4:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
        
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2610 ]]; then
        `chown db5:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
    
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2710 ]]; then
        `chown db6:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
            
    elif [[ ${path_owners[$j]} -eq 2400 ]]; then
        `chown db7:5000 ${path_owners_names[$j]}`
        
    fi
    j=$((j+1))

done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code of the script. (I have seen a very similar question somewhere on a stackoverflow site recently...)

Comment: @Bodo Actually that post was mine but it was messy, people dont understand it. So I created a new environment, I got the outputs properly and created a new post to be clearer.

Comment: I think it would have been better to improve the original question or at least to include a link to the original question.

Comment: First, remove the backquotes around the `chown` commands. These are wrong. There is a missing space in `chown db3:5000${path_owners_names[$j]}`. If you re-typed your script, copy&paste it to the question to avoid such errors. Add some debug output to your script to see if it works as you expect. For example, add a line `echo i: "$i" j: "$j" owner: "${path_owners[$j]}" path: "${path_owners_names[$j]}"` in the loop after `do` and check the output. If you need further help, show the modified script and the output in the question.

Comment: You didn't even take into account what was suggested to improve in your last question. This is in no way better or more understandable IMO.